# How to get access to the underlying component of a react html element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to create a `<Breadcrumb>` component which receives a `<Link>` component as a dependency.

This could be a `<Link>` component from `react-router-dom` or an `<a>` component.

How can I get direct access to the `<a>` component so that I may inject it into `<Breadcrumb>`?

---

Here is a brief example of what I'm trying to do.

```
const createBreadcrumbComponent = (Link) => {
    return function Breadcrumb(props) {
        // return JSX that renders this Link component 
        // A basic example:
        return <Link href="/">{"Home"}</Link>
    }
}
```

An example of using this with `react-router-dom`s own `<Link` component:

```
// import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
const Breadcrumb = createBreadcrumbComponent(Link);
```

I would like do the same as above, but substitute `Link` with `a`. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an actual component that represents `a` (with `React.createElement()` we pass the string "a" instead).

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `ref` to access the underlying DOM element from a React Component. But, this is not always the case.

Following are the cases, which will enable you to use `ref` -

1. The component is a native HTML element, for eg - `a`, `div`, `img` etc.
2. The React native component is wrapped with a `forwardRef`. This doc explains it nicely - https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

An example for using `ref` can be seen below -

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const Comp = () => {
  const elRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(elRef.current); // -> the p element
  }, []);

  return <p ref={elRef}>Hello</p>;
}
```

There is a third way of getting the underlying element, but I don't recommend it since it is deprecated. You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(Component)`. This is a part of `react-dom` package.
You can read more about it here - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to create a wrapper around `<a>`, for instance:

```
const A = (props) => <a {...props}/>;
const Breadcrumb = createBreadcrumbComponent(A);
```

I was hoping there would be a way to obtain a component directly from React that already encompasses the `<a>` element